# Sequelize Maximum call stack size exceeded with associations

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

this is my first question :) I need your help, my problem is that I have associations in sequelize the first:

```
 AssistantGroupModel.hasOne(StaffGroup(), {
        sourceKey: 'staff_group_id',
        foreignKey: 'id',
        as: 'staff_group'
    });
```

and second:

```
StaffGroupModel.hasMany(AssistantGroup(),{
        sourceKey: 'id',
        foreignKey: 'staff_group_id',
        as: 'members'
    })
```

When I need to make a query with "instance" this error ocurrs:

**Maximum call stack size exceeded**

why? thank you for your help.

Comment: what's the difference between AssistantGroupModel and AssistantGroup? The same about StaffGroupModel and StaffGroup

Comment: the diference is that AssistantGroupModel is the class and AssistantGroup is a const function that returns the class :)

Comment: Show how your models are associated

Answer (score 0):

Modify your first association as follows -

```
AssistantGroupModel.belongsTo(StaffGroup, {
        sourceKey: 'id',
        foreignKey: 'staff_group_id',
        as: 'staff_group'
    });
```

I am wondering why you have used `function call` like `StaffGroup() and AssistantGroup()` while defining association. To the best of my knowledge, it is not required.